# In Java which approach for reading files by bytes is better:

Tags: java, idioms

I am trying to decide which way is better for reading a file, bytes at a time. Is one of these two ways better than the other and if so why?

1)

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_RETRIEVAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead = fileContent.read(buffer);
while (bytesRead != 1) {
    fileOnDisk.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = fileContent.read(buffer);
}
```

2)

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_RETRIEVAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
while (true) {
    int bytesRead = fileContent.read(buffer);
    if (-1 == bytesRead)
         {break;}
    fileOnDisk.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another common idiom is this. It has neither a redundancy nor a break statement.

```
int bytesRead;
while ( -1 != (bytesRead = fileContent.read(buffer)) {
       ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that has advantage of removing the while(true) break business but also removes the need to have the bytesRead = fileContent.read(buffer); appear in two places. It is a little awkward to read though.

Comment: You're welcome. The idiom dates at least back to C programming. As you see it more, it may begin to seem less awkward, and more like a familiar construct.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, (just fix it and change your `while(bytesRead != 1)` to `while(bytesRead != -1)`). It states clearer when to finish the while loop.